# iOS TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hola estoy teniendo un problema con la implementación de la función de guardado en un TabBarController, para el cual, he seguido un consejo de alguien de la comunidad y al cual se lo agradezco muchísimo, pero tengo un problema y es que no consigo que funcione.

Como siempre, dejo el repositorio de [GitHub](https://github.com/anonimous231/TabBarController) para que cualquiera pueda descargar el proyecto y me pueda echar un cable.

El problema es que desde cada una de las vistas del TabBarController, necesito poder hacer cambios en la comida en concreto, es decir, si estoy en la vista del nombre de la comida y hago cualquier cambio y le doy a guardar, eso me guardará el nombre nuevo, el cual, al volver a la lista de comidas, me aparecerá actualizado, lo mismo necesito con la imagen y la valoración.

Llevo ya un tiempo dándole vueltas, pero no consigo que funcione, os agradecería que me echárais una mano, ya que me lo han pedido y ni siquiera el profesor me puede ayudar... :S

Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Que tal si usas CoreData para poder manipular la informacion de tu base de datos, asi podrias implementar nsfetchedresultscontroller y este responderia a cualquier cambio y ejecutaria cualquier accion que tu necesites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que pude entenderte, lo que necesitas es que tu ViewController (tabBar 1), se actualize cuando tu ViewController (tabBar 3) modifique algún entity o model. Existen varios métodos o formas que podrían ayudarte pero la opción más fácil son las Notifications. Las notificaciones se pueden enviar entre viewControllers unos envían y otros escuchan los eventos y reaccionan a ellos, entonces te muestro un ejemplo.

---

ViewController(tabBar 1)

func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(observer(notification:)), name: Notification.Name.dataChange, object: nil)
}

func observer(notification: NSNotification) {
 //Aquí harás un reloadData o updateUI para actualizar la información.
}

---

ViewController(tabBar 3)

func downloadData() {

//Después de descargar información o modificarla

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .dataChange, object: nil)
}

// Utilities
extension Notification.Name {
    static let dataChange = Notification.Name("dataChange")
}